# Drupal 7, superfish menu hidden in garland theme

Tags: theming

I am using the default theme `garland` in `Drupal 7.23` with a `superfish` menu put on the `first sidebar` block . (the side on the left).

But when I try to open the menu, and on my content block I have a view or a nivo slideshow block the menu is hidden. Where should I put the z-index? (tried on the theme and on the menu but nothing worked)

Thank you

Comment: Since garland theme has no "main-menu", i have edited the id "sidebar-first" and now it works. Thanks for the tip, and I will read how to subclass the theme so I can put a custom CSS instead modify the standard theme. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `page.tpl.php` page search with keyword menu,

```
 <div id="main-menu" style="z-index:99">
```

you can put style `z-inex` here.